# Get the id of data selected on a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying some data selected from database with the code below; I am trying to echo a delete button on the table, so when the user clicks on delete i want the id of the row  to be sent via get method;

my issue that i am having is that i want the value of the selected key in my case'post_id'to be sent via get; any suggestion how to get that id and send it via get?

```
    //select and display all posts on a table.
$query="SELECT * FROM posts ";
$results=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "post_content") {
        continue;
    }
    if ($key == "post_img") {
        $value = "<img width='100px' src='../imgs/$value' class='img-responsive'>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
}


    echo "<td><button class='confirm-delete'><a href='posts.php?delete='> Delete</a></button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: does the table have an ID column?

Answer (score 0):

If the column name is post_id, you should be able to get it in your foreach loop since you have a star (*) in your select command. Add an if statement that checks if $key is "post_id" and saves $value to a temporary variable if it's true. You can then use that value when you make the delete link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column with the id (named  id) ..  You should add your row  id to your delete=   eg:

```
echo "<td><button class='confirm-delete'>
     <a href='posts.php?delete='". $row['id'] . "> Delete</a></button></td>";
```